# append a rvalue vector to a vector in O(1) time

Tags: c++, c++17, rvalue

I was wondering how to append the rvalue vector in constant time (O(1)) to another vector.
I know methods by using `std::insert` and `std::move`, but is there any method to append a `std::vector<T>&&` to `std::vector<T>&` in O(1) time.

Comment: Short Answer: There isn't.

Comment: An std::vector is required by the Standard to be contiguous in memory.  So append has to add one element at a time to the target std::vector, extending it's backing store as required.

Comment: ok, so what would be the list of data structures in which this would be possible, would it be possible with data structures like `unordered_set`, `unordered_map` etc.?

Comment: @Vishnu: No. You're looking for a linked list, which is pretty much the only data structure with O(1) insertion time (you must use `splice` for `std::list` to get this).

Comment: @NicolBolas thanks, completely forgot abt that one .

Comment: Remember that while the insert is a cheap operation with a linked list, virtually everything else you do is now *more* expensive. How much more expensive and if that added expense exceed the gains of cheaper insert depends on the usage pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would being an rvalue matter at all to this? Big-O notation counts the number of operations done in a process. Whether those operations are copy or move, if the number of operations performed is directly proportional to the number of items in the source list, then it is an O(n) process.

And if you're going to copy/move a contiguous sequence of elements into another contiguous sequence of elements, with the result being contiguous, that process must be be O(n) (at least), where n is the number of elements in the source sequence. Even if it did a `memcpy` of the source elements, `memcpy` of some sequence of `T`s is O(n) on the number of `T`s in the sequence.